# Wordpress Theming, Unable to locate stylesheets in scripts.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

(I am following this Book "Bootstrap Site Blueprint" and I am now in chapter 3. It introduces the use of Roots as a starting theme for Wordpress. )
I am creating custom theme for Wordpress, and I encountered a problem when I try to connect to my own stylesheet by modifying the `scripts.php`.

Here's my file structure:

```
|bootstrappin-theme
   |assets
       |css
           |main.css
   |lib
       |scripts.php
```

And here's the related code in `scripts.php`

```
if (WP_ENV === 'development') {
   $assets = array(
      'css'       => '/assets/css/main.css',
      'js'        => '/assets/js/scripts.js',
      'modernizr' => '/assets/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js',
      'jquery'    => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js'
  );
} 
else {
    $get_assets = file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/assets/manifest.json');
    $assets     = json_decode($get_assets, true);
    $assets     = array(
      'css'       => '/assets/css/main.min.css?' . $assets['assets/css/main.min.css']['hash'],
      'js'        => '/assets/js/scripts.min.js?' . $assets['assets/js/scripts.min.js']['hash'],
      'modernizr' => '/assets/js/vendor/modernizr.min.js',
      'jquery'    => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'
    );
}

wp_enqueue_style('roots_css', get_template_directory_uri() . $assets['css'], false, null);
```

Then I checked the browser, there's a 404 error requesting "main.css" with the url read from request log:"127.0.0.1/wordpress/assets/css"

---

So I changed the path for `css` from `'/assets/css/main.css'` to

`'/wp-content/themes/bootstrappin-theme/assets/css/main.css'`.

It now looks like:

```
if (WP_ENV === 'development') {
$assets = array(
  'css'       => '/wp-content/themes/bootstrappin-theme/assets/css/main.css',
...
wp_enqueue_style('roots_css', get_template_directory_uri() . $assets['css'], false, null);
```

However, it's still 404 error and weirdly, when I checked the path in browser, The path to `main.css` is still

**main.css**

**127.0.0.1/wordpress/assets/css**

The tricky part I found is that, the path output will never reach my `bootstrappin-theme` folder and its

behaviour is weird.

---

***Examlpe 1***

So for example, if I change the code in `scripts.php` to

`/wp-content/themes/bootstrappin-theme-example/assets/css/main.css`

the path output in browser will ignore everything before `/wp-content/themes/bootstrappin-theme-example` and it will be like this:

**127.0.0.1/wordpress/assets/css**

Yes, exactly like before.

---

***Example 2***

If I change the code to

`/wp-content/themes-example/bootstrappin-theme/assets/css/main.css`

The output will be:

**127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/themes-example/bootstrappin-theme/assets/css/main.css**

---

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_template_directory_uri-issues-with-sub-directory-theme).

To avoid this, modify */wp-content/themes/bootstrappin-theme/lib/config.php*
and just turn this line (ususally line 6) to comments:

`// add_theme_support('rewrites');`